# Elasticsearch Change Node Name via REST API

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to update the node name (node.name) via the REST API?

I have tried to do it like so with no luck.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_nodes/CTOdAAalSQ2ZOI6-VsuO0w/settings -d '{
    "persistent" : {
        "node.name" : "nodeX"
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by editing config file elasticsearch.yml.

or

Use cluster reroute

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
"commands":[{"allocate": {"index":"","shard":0,"node":"node_name", "allow_primary" : 1}}]
}'
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html

Comment: Thanks Siddardha, but I am aware of this. I am specifically wanting to update the node.name via the REST API.